# How to retrieve in java a custom attribute of a particular view object?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-styles

I have this styles :

```
  <!-- EditText on a blue background -->
  <style name="BlueBGTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText">
    <item name="alfloatingToolbarStyle">@style/alfloatingToolbarDarkStyle</item>
  </style>

  <!-- default EditText -->
  <style name="AppThemeEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText">
  </style>

  <!-- default Theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppThemeEditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="@attr/BlueBGTextViewStyle">@style/BlueBGTextView</item>    
  </style>
```

Then i create on the fly in java the view (EditText) via the constructor:

```
public ALEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,  int defStyleRes)
```

In this way i define on the fly the design of the EditText by assigning to it the defStyleAttr.

Now i have another library that is responsible to create for the editText a popup window. To know the design to apply to the popup the library (that is an external library i build) need to check the value of the `alfloatingToolbarStyle` attribute. but i don't know how the library can check the attribute alfloatingToolbarStyle of a particular view (the library just receive the param: `(Context context)` ... but i can add also `(View view)` if it's necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library in charge of the dialog doesn't know either your custom attribute or your custom style as they don't belong to it.

The style to use should be pass as parameter when you call the library to create the dialog, so the logic to define which style to use should be handle by the code calling the library and not the library itself.

Comment: i prefere instead to add a "tag" (ie: a custom attribute) in the xml of the EditText instead. is it not possible like this ?

Comment: You can set a tag to a view but it's different than a custom attribute.
But what do you call a library? Is it a library or just another class of your project?

Comment: it's a generic library i made. this Library create a popup window on the top of a view. and to call this library i simply do : mFloatingToolbar = new ALFloatingToolbar(View view); and i would like to know if it's possible to inspect the attribute of the view to find `<item name="alfloatingToolbarStyle">@style/al_floating_toolbar_dark</item>`

Comment: But alfloatingToolbarStyle is part of your custom EditText and not known from the library (except if your custom EditText is in another library included in this library), so how the library can get this attribute if it doesn't know it? That why the best option is to not pass the view to the library but directly the style or anything like an enum item, for the library to know which style to use without to care about the view. Especially if you want your library to be generic

Answer (score 0):

Please define style in EditText tag using below code...

```
android:theme="@style/BlueBGTextView"
```